# Why month x-ticks are labelled wrongly in a datetime index?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset of 12 values, with the index being a `datetime64` type and I want to plot a bar graph of the data with the `x-ticks` showing the Month in English. I have used the `MonthLocator` and `DateFormatter` functions of matplotlib. These are working for one dataset but not with the other one. The x-ticks months are labelled wrongly. `January should be the first index.`

Dataset --> `full_corr`

```
              corr
timestamp   
2010-01-31  0.367613
2010-02-28  0.178960
2010-03-31  0.217788
2010-04-30  0.146214
2010-05-31  0.201297
2010-06-30  0.609486
2010-07-31  0.659257
2010-08-31  0.397254
2010-09-30  0.729701
2010-10-31  0.916465
2010-11-30  0.533646
2010-12-31  0.893937
```

Code used -->

```
plt.bar(full_corr.index, full_corr['corr'], width=10) # some bugs are there
ax = plt.gca()
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()
month_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(month_fmt)
```

Output is -->
[Output Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3cNr.jpg)

**But** when I plot the dataframe directly by using `df.plot(kind="bar")`, the x-ticks are showed properly in the full datetime format.

Comment: What do you mean "labelled wrongly"? They look like what you asked for.  What did you want?

Comment: First index should be January right? @JodyKlymak

Comment: The locator is finding the nearest month.  The nearest month to 2010-01-31 is 2010-Feb.

Comment: Thank you @JodyKlymak . But why does it do that? Why need nearest when the month is given?

Comment: The xaxis is a scale - think of plotting a data point once an hour.  If you just wish to label bars, then its better to just use categorical plotting as the accepted answer below.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I think it is more correct to say that by default the matplotlib `MonthLocator` places a tick on the first day of each month included in the range of time within the x-axis limits. The ticks are processed independently from the timestamps of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 2010-01-31 is too near to 2010-02-01. So when you set width to 10, it overlays Feb.

i.stack.imgur.com/EDewS.png

A soution to solve this is to convert 2010-01-31 to 2010-01.

- [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) is used to convert series to `datetime`.
- [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) converts `datetime` series to a string in our desired format.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

full_corr = pd.read_csv("1.csv")

# Below two lines are same with full_corr['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(full_corr['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
full_corr['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(full_corr['timestamp'])
full_corr['timestamp'] = full_corr['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m'))

full_corr['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(full_corr['timestamp'])

plt.bar(full_corr['timestamp'], full_corr['corr'], width=10) # some bugs are there
ax = plt.gca()

locator = mdates.MonthLocator()
month_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(month_fmt)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, when we change column to a datetime type, it adds `01` as day right? Since it is datetime and have to be a valid date?

Comment: Yes, this can also be demostrated by adding `print(full_corr['timestamp'])` after all conversion finished.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `matplotlib.dates` `MonthLocator` places the ticks on the first day of each month by default, whereas the DatetimeIndex of your dataset has a so-called ['month end' frequency](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases). Here are two simple solutions to this problem.

**Solution 1: add `bymonthday=-1` to `MonthLocator`**

```
plt.bar(full_corr.index, full_corr['corr'], width=10)
ax = plt.gca()
locator = mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=-1)
month_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(month_fmt)
```

[image: solution1]

**Solution 2: resample the dataframe to a 'month start' frequency**

```
full_corr_ms = full_corr.resample('MS').sum()
plt.bar(full_corr_ms.index, full_corr_ms['corr'], width=10)
ax = plt.gca()
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()
month_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(month_fmt)
```

[image: solution2]

Comment: This was helpful.